# monk query inside async loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-async, monk

I have a list of products, each product has a list of ingredients stored in a file:

```
{ "name": "test", "inci": ['a', 'b', 'n'] },
{ "name": "test", "inci": ['a', 'b', 'n'] }
```

I need to check the presence of the given ingredient inside my MongoDB collection:

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/mydb');
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");

var str = fs.readFileSync("products-parsed.json", "utf8");

var products = JSON.parse('[' + str + ']');

// collections
var ingredients = db.get('ingredients');

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

async.forEach(products, function(p, nextProduct) {
  async.forEach(p.inci, function(i, nextIngredient) {

    // Escape characters to prepare the regex
    i = escapeRegExp(i.replace('*', '')).trim();

    // Query the ingredient name passing a regexp as value to look for case insensitive matches
    ingredients.findOne({name: new RegExp(i, 'i')}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { console.log(err); }

      if (!result) {
        console.log('ERROR:', i);
      } else {
        console.log('OK:', i);
      }

      // Proceed to next ingredient
      nextIngredient();

    });

  }, function(err) {
    // Proceed to next product
    nextProduct();
  });
}, function(err) {
  // end
  process.exit();
});
```

### Note:

If I use a small input array (less than 2.000 rows or so) then everything works.
If I use the entire array (15.000 rows) it doesn't, each product is logged by `console.log(i)` but the query is not performed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to your data , it queries in name section `/a/i` this record.

Comment: yes that's right, I'm performing a case insensitive query. I don't think it's a problem because if I do `products = {p: [products.p[0]]}` it correctly run the entire script

Answer (score 0):

Give your regex in correct format according to [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

```
ingredients.findOne( { name : { $regex : new RegExp(i, 'i') } }
```

BTW, I don't know , will `monk` library pass queries like `mongoose` , try and let me know on comments.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change anything.. even replacing the regex with a hard coded string make the query run, looks like the findOne is not even read

Comment: Move `next2();` inside the query success result. I have just saw that line.

Comment: yup I've noticed it and fixed it, doing so, the query is executed if I limit the input array to 1 element, but if I pass the complete array nothing changes :(

Comment: There may be monk's issue ? Have you tried instead of regex query normal findOne query for any name ?

Comment: yes I've tried replacing the regex with just a static string without success

Comment: @FezVrasta Is your `dbname` and `collection-name` , can you check them?

Comment: it's correct... I've tried limiting the number of items in my input array and it works if I give it less than ~1000 elements...

Comment: @FezVrasta Then , It might be monk's issue. I may advice `mongoose`